# hard coded html / php pages on local host directory don't show up in WP dashboard

Tags: pages

My hard coded html static file I converted to php pages on my localhost directory don't show up in WP dashboard.

I'm re-purposing a static HTML site to WP. My files don't show up in the dashboard.

I believe I had the database setup correct in myPHP-admin, not sure what the issues is

Comment: WP do not show hard coded static html/php by default. you need to elaborate how do you want your html fie to show.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how WordPress works. The WordPress content is pulled dynamically from the database and uses templates to create an outline of what the website should look like.

`header.php` which would contain the top part of your website.

`footer.php` which would contain the bottom part of your website.

`page.php` which would hold the page content of your website. The content of which is held in the database and served using [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
if( have_posts() ) {

    while( have_posts() ) {

        the_post();
        the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
        the_content();

    }

}
```

You need to create pages in WordPress ( either programatically or manually ) and populate the content. Another method is to create [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) and assign unique layouts to specific pages.

I would suggest looking at already build themes to get a better understanding of how they layout and pull their content such: [Twenty XYZ Themes](https://wordpress.org/themes/author/wordpressdotorg/) by WordPress. Additionally there's the [Theme Development](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/) guide in The Handbook which is well worth a read.

Comment: Because I have the html static file already coded, they wont be included?

I have a bare bones child- theme already created based on the bootstrap theme

So in essence I have to "create" those already existing blank pages and then migrate the html code in those pages?

Comment: Right, you would break up your static file into 3 parts. Header, Footer, Page body and put them in their relative files ( listed above ). Using The Loop to pull page content from pages you've already created in the WordPress Admin -> Pages.

Comment: Okay so in the dashboard I create blank :

home
index
about
etc...

How do I access the pages in my local host on my PC?